# HTML Form Button onclick using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I have a problem where I am trying to change the text inputs in a form to the color black after clicking  the "Reset button" using Javascript.

I had considered using *onReset* in the HTML to solve the problem, however, problem states that I must solve this using **Javascript only** (or JQuery if needed), hence the below **HTML below is not editable**. I have considered document.forms and getElementbyID("contact") but no idea what to do from there.

Any help appreciated thanks!

Here  is my HTML:

```
<form id="contact" action="" onsubmit="checkContactForm( this ); return false;" >
<p>
  <label for="name">First name:</label>
  <input name="name" id="name" onfocus="resetField( this );" />
</p>
  <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" onfocus="resetField( this );"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
</p>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var requiredFields = [ "name", "message" ];


function resetField( theField ) {
  if ( theField.value == "Error" ) {
theField.value = "";
theField.style.color = "#000";
  }
}

function resetForm( theForm ){
for ( i in requiredFields ) {
    var fieldName = requiredFields[ i ];
    var theField = theForm[ fieldName ];
    theField.style.color = "#000";
    theField.value = "";
}
```

Comment: Where's the `resetField` function you're calling?

Comment: sorry i didn't add it to the question above

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to change the text inputs in a form to the color black after clicking the "Reset button" using Javascript.

This can be done using `click` event in `jQuery`. Like this:

```
$('button[type="reset"]').click(function () {
  /* change the color using
   * $('input').css('color', '#000'); #000 is black..
   */
}
```

This way the color for the input text will change to black when a click is made on reset button.

jQuery code to reset the input is:

```
$('input[type="name"]').val('');
```

Note the single qoutes in the val method, this would remove the val and will replace it with an empty string. You can use double qoutes too as `val("")`.

```
var requiredFields = [ "name", "message" ];
```

This is not the correct method, you should use the `input[name="name"]`. However, you can use a simple jQuery to change the input for the ID or class.

You are using:

```
resetField( this );
```

Which won't work, because in `script` tag you are using

```
resetForm
```

And since these both don't match, no script would run!

Good luck,

Comment: sorry i also have resetfield in my code, I didn't add it above because I thought it was irrelevant to the problem (added now). I will try your solution soon, thanks.

Comment: Oh, its ok! So what is the issue now? The code is good .. where does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is below

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="nothing" id="testForm">
            <label for="textInput">Text Input</label>
            <input type="text" id="textInput" name="textInput">
            <label for="textAreaInput">Text Area Input</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="textAreaInput" name="textAreaInput"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton"> <input type="reset" id="resetButton">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lib/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code using jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#resetButton").click(function() {
            // change color of all textarea fields to red
            $("#testForm textarea").css('color', 'red');
            // change color of all text input fields to red
            $("#testForm input[type='text']").css('color', 'red');
            return false;
        });
    }
);
```